# Who is it possible that gita is written in classical sanskrit and not in vedic sanskrit?

Tags: sanskrit, gita, language

> **The Baudhāyana sūtras are a group of Vedic Sanskrit texts which cover dharma**, daily ritual, mathematics, etc. They belong to the Taittiriya branch of the Krishna Yajurveda school and are among the earliest texts of the genre, perhaps compiled in the 8th to 6th centuries BCE.[Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudhayana_sutras)

In the Baudhāyana sūtras we find a very interesting verse :

> In case the country is not appropriate, one is without money, then he can normally do puja in his mind or offer this is because Bhagavan says- **“those who give me leaf, flower, fruit or water with devotion I eat that which has been offered by my pure minded devotee”** .(Baudhayana Grhya Sutra 2.22.9)

"Those who - - - - - - pure minded". This qoute is referring to gita 9:26.

> [BG 9.26](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/9/verse/26): If one offers to Me with devotion a leaf, a flower, a fruit, or even water, I delightfully partake of that article offered with love by My devotee in pure consciousness.

Baudhāyana sūtras is written in vedic sanskrit Where as   gita is written in classical sanskrit.
How is this possible.

Gita was revealed in the battle of Mahabharata, the commenly accepted date is [3067 Bce](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurukshetra_War#:%7E:text=Sadananda%2C%20based%20on%20translation%20work,took%20place%20in%203067%20BCE.).

But Baudhāyana sūtras was written in around 8th to 6th centuries bce.

So gita predates Baudhāyana sūtras. But how is it possible that gita is written in classical sanskrit and not in vedic sanskrit.

---

<sup>https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45738/22556</sup>

Comment: https://qr.ae/pGTk9Q

Comment: @Dark Knight, do you have a link for the english translation of Baudhayana Grihya Sutras?

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru what do you mean by the above link

Comment: It is just a hindutva-type link denying that there are two languages - Vedic and Classical Sanskrit.  Linguistics makes it crystal clear that they are different and also that classical sanskrit is not derived from vedic sanskrit.  They are very close, but are not the same. @dark knight

Comment: you seem to be comparing English translations...not one original Sanskrit text to another Sanskrit text. Pointing out similar English phrase translations is not relevant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is merely comparing English translations. Not relevant to comparing ancient Sanskrit to modern Sanskrit

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda no I am not comparing two translations

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda see this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45738/22556

Comment: @DarkKnight Classical vs Vedic Sanskrit is a colonial misunderstanding like Aryan Invasion. Baudhayana Sutras were written at 800 BCE says Google

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru there is a difference

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru see this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45670/22556

Comment: @DarkKnight I reject that answer. The user I quote you has studied Vedas with commentaries and all traditional works of Panini, Yaska and Upanishads Bramha Sutras etc in Sanskrit. He is Vedic Scholar and my greatest authority

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru see the answer is not saying that they are different(completely) but there is a difference between them. I have even give you the example.

Comment: Now if I assume you are right then your logic is contradicting yourself ! This is result of your qn. You are forced to think that Baudhayana was written before than Gita which is proved wrong by facts @DarkKnight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Devanagari is identical in both cases:

पत्रं पुष्पं फलं तोयं यो मे भक्त्या प्रयच्छति |
तदहं भक्त्युपहृतमश्नामि प्रयतात्मन: || 26||

patraṁ puṣhpaṁ phalaṁ toyaṁ yo me bhaktyā prayachchhati
tadahaṁ bhaktyupahṛitam aśhnāmi prayatātmanaḥ

patram pushpam phalam toyam yo me bhaktya prayachchhati
tadaham bhaktyupahritam ashnami prayatatmanah

This is in pure classical sanskrit.  Baudhayana Grihya Sutra is in language that is almost Classical - must have been written when Vedic Sanskrit had almost died out as a living language.

Why this identical verse appears in two scriptures needs to be explained.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: But why was gita revealed in sanskrit. If Baudhayana Grihya Sutra is in almost classical sanskrit. Because it was written in time wear vedic sanskrit almost died out. Then we can conclude may be 200 years before the Sutra was written people spoke vedic sanskrit. It still doesn't line up. Because Mahabharata is about 3000 BCE

Comment: linguistically Mahabharata is quite young, almost as young as Puranic Sanskrit.  Unless you give fantastic interpretations for "yavana" and so forth, there isn't any way MBh could be from 3000 bc @darkknight

Comment: @DarkKnight - Mahabharata is definitely from 3000BC. Yavanas/Mlecchas etc. have existed for a long time. Science simply hasn't caught up with evidence.